# how to supply data to a php array from an external file?

Tags: php, html

i am using phplot to plot a graph in a web page, and i have the following code for it,

```
   <?php
     //Include the code
    require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/phplot-6.1.0/phplot.php';

     //Define the object
     $plot = new PHPlot();

    //Define some data

     $example_data = array(
     array('a',3),
     array('b',5),
     array('c',7),
     array('d',8),
     array('e',4),
     array('f',6),
      array('g',7)
      );
     $plot->SetDataValues($example_data);

     //Turn off X axis ticks and labels because they get in the way:
     $plot->SetXTickLabelPos('none');
     $plot->SetXTickPos('none');

      //Draw it
      $plot->DrawGraph();
       ?>
```

i don't want to define the data as in $example_data, but i want to read or upload this from an external file like txt or json, please suggest how to achieve this and what can be the type of the external file to be uploaded ?

Comment: Have you tried anything or done any research?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you don't seem to have bothered searching the excellent php.net documentation, which should have been your first place to find an answer.

Comment: i am trying this since two days, tried to use json also

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can :

```
$file = 'your.json';
$example_data = json_decode( @file_get_contents( $file ) );
```

your.json ( for example ) :

```
[["a",3],["b",5],["c",7],["d",8],["e",4],["f",6],["g",7]]
```

updated !

for create dynamic json file :

```
$data = array();

$data[] = array( 'a' , 3 );
$data[] = array( 'b' , 1 );
$data[] = array( 'c' , 2 );
$data[] = array( 'd' , 4 );
$data[] = array( 'e' , 8 );
$data[] = array( 'f' , 6 );
$data[] = array( '6' , 7 );

echo json_encode( $data );
```

**another way :**

`make_data.php` :

```
$data = array();

$data[] = array( 'a' , 3 );
$data[] = array( 'b' , 1 );
$data[] = array( 'c' , 2 );
$data[] = array( 'd' , 4 );
$data[] = array( 'e' , 8 );
$data[] = array( 'f' , 6 );
$data[] = array( '6' , 7 );

return $data;
```

and for read :

```
$example_data = include( 'make_data.php' );
```

Comment: thanks,i have this solution already, but i am sure about the format or contents of this your.json, i have tried all kinds of formats to match this kind of $example_data array, but i am not able to get it, i need the exact format for that array so that the phplot works, otherwise it doesn't work, can you help regarding this ?

Comment: @Sachin updated answer, see again

Comment: tried the above json format, but i am getting this error on the output page, Drawgraph(): No data array, somehow it doesn't seem to read this data.

Comment: @Sachin if use first way : you must $file = 'http://localhost/data.php'; but added another way, that is better

Comment: what is this data.php, is this another file

Comment: @Sachin see `make_data.php` code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
   <?php
     //Include the code
    require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/phplot-6.1.0/phplot.php';

     //Define the object
     $plot = new PHPlot();

    //Define some data

     $example_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("some_external_file.json"),true);
     $plot->SetDataValues($example_data);

     //Turn off X axis ticks and labels because they get in the way:
     $plot->SetXTickLabelPos('none');
     $plot->SetXTickPos('none');

      //Draw it
      $plot->DrawGraph();
       ?>


some_external_file.json

{"a":3,"b":5,"c":7,"d":8,"e":4,"f":6,"g":7};
```

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be a fairly common solution is to simply return a php array.

include.php:

```
<?php
return array(14, 34, 342, 4252);
```

index.php:

```
<?php

$data=include('include.php');
```